# Why am I having this error with PieChart?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

first time here asking a question.
I don't know how to code but I need an app and don't have the money to pay someone yet.

I've been having the same error again and again but I can't understand why and how to solve it.

here's the code :

```
Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(top: 16),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 0, 0),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6)),
                width: 300,
                height: 200,
                child: Column(
                  children:[
                    const Text(
                      'Votre Patrimoine',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            LayoutBuilder(
                              builder: (context, constraints) {
                                return const PieChart(
                                  dataMap: {
                                    '1': 25,
                                    '2': 75,
                                  },
                                  colorList: [
                                    Colors.blue,
                                    Colors.red,
                                  ],
                                );
                              },
                            )

                          ],
                            )
                      ]
                        ),
                        Column(
                          
                          children: [
                            const Text('Les 24 dernières heures',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                            Text(dayvariations,
                            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white))
                          ]
                          
                        )
                      ],)
                    )
                  ),
                
          ]
```

here's a part of the error VsCode gives me :

> RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPositionedBox#4dc8d relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
> package:flutter/…/rendering/box.dart:1
> Failed assertion: line 2001 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
PieChart

I was expecting to have a Piechart

Comment: Hey Emerick, This happens when a widget has no constrained height which makes it gets an infinite height or width. You should wrap in another widget like sizedBox. Can you share the complete file ?

Comment: Do you have a listview or a gridview somewhere ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when a widget has no constrained height which makes it gets an infinite height or width.

PieChart needs a defined or constrained height, you should wrap in another widget like sizedBox or a container with a heigth.

Like this :

```
                        Row(children: [
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          LayoutBuilder(
                            builder: (context, constraints) {
                              return Container(
                                height: 500,
                                child: PieChart(
                                  dataMap: {
                                    '1': 25,
                                    '2': 75,
                                  },
                                  colorList: [
                                    Colors.blue,
                                    Colors.red,
                                  ],
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          )
                        ],
                      )
                    ]),
```